# java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should not happen as headers() should only be called while a record is processed

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Starting up a Stream application (using Kafka Streams) fails with the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should not happen as headers() should only be called while a record is processed"

This seems to only happen when I start up the application if there is already data in the topic. If the topic is empty and I start pushing data to it, all is fine.

Would someone know why this would happen?

Thanks

```
This should not happen as headers() should only be called while a record is processed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should not happen as headers() should only be called while a record is processed
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.headers(AbstractProcessorContext.java:149)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putInternal(CachingKeyValueStore.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.put(CachingKeyValueStore.java:222)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.put(CachingKeyValueStore.java:37)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.put(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:153)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl$KeyValueStoreReadWriteDecorator.put(ProcessorContextImpl.java:446)
        at fr.mediametrie.GeoIPEnrichmentProcessor.transform(GeoIPEnrichmentProcessor.java:97)
        at fr.mediametrie.GeoIPEnrichmentProcessor.transform(GeoIPEnrichmentProcessor.java:1)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.TransformerSupplierAdapter$1.transform(TransformerSupplierAdapter.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.TransformerSupplierAdapter$1.transform(TransformerSupplierAdapter.java:36)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatTransform$KStreamFlatTransformProcessor.process(KStreamFlatTransform.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:364)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:199)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:420)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:890)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774)
```

Comment: Check out this FAQ: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#why-do-i-get-an-illegalstateexception-when-accessing-record-metadata

Answer (score 4):

Building on the information Matthias shared, here's a practical example:

- Returning the same transformer object (also valid for Processor and ValueTransformer) results in an `IllegalStateException`:

```
var transformer = new Transformer();

inputStream
  .transformValues(() -> transformer)
// further operations...
```

- Returning a new instance each time prevents the exception:

```
inputStream
  .transformValues(() -> new Transformer())
// further operations...
```

p.s: I am aware that the documentation is quite clear, but hope this saves some scrolling.